# avaliable memory + used memory is less than total memory

Tags: ram, swap

ive noticed a strange behavior that the computer crashes when the usage is slightly bigger than 3000mb. and the swap is used even before reaching the 3000mb as if the computer just had it.

thats the result of my `free -m`

```
......total..used..free..shared..buff/cache..available
Mem:..3834...2009..715...523.....1109........1066
Swap:.2047...1811..236
```

what is hapenning here? ive been with this problem since a long time and its not annoying but limiting the usage of my computer

**EDIT**
this is my current result:

```
......total...used..free.....shared......buff/cache.....available
Mem:...3834...1818...385........999............1631...........787
```

it is getting worse

Comment: Do you observe "oom" (out of memory) log entries anywhere in /var/log files? Perhaps `/var/log/kern/log` and/or `/var/log/syslog`. And yes, some memory is reserved, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980246/why-does-available-physical-memory-appear-to-increase-after-boot/980258#980258)

Comment: yes i got some https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/4mfv

Comment: also i noticed that it is worse today... the sum of the available plus free is now 2605... its like im losing ram from time to time what do i do?

Comment: It appears you do not have enough memory for what you are trying to do with your computer. You could try to increase swap space, but you could just end up thrashing as you swap in and out of main memory.

Comment: i just can use half of the ram on the computer, thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment because I don't have enough reputation, I hope that's allright.

I dont't really see a problem here. Your Used, Free and buffer add up to your total memory. What seems to be happening is that your buffer/cache is running full. But thats not really a problem. Linux will store things that are regularily accessed in memory before writing it to the disk, to increase access speeds. Thats the buffer/cache. But this memory is not really "lost" to you, linux will shrink the cache automatically to make more memory available to processes if they need it.

If you want to manually free some cache, you might want to have a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/

Comment: The real issue would be the crashing not how the memory adds up.